# Sending messages from C++ windows desktop app to DLL

Tags: c++, windows, message

I use Embarcadero C++ Builder, but I guess the IDE doesn't matter. My application loads a dll containing a TForm (named TCalibrateForm), which is displayed on screen and stays there, so the main application and the form contained in the dll exist simultaneously.

I need both TForms to communicate, and for that I use FindWindow() and SendMessage(), in the main app, in the following way:

```
TCopyDataStruct data;
HWND handle = FindWindow(
    L"TCalibrateForm",
    nullptr);
if (handle)
{
    LRESULT r = SendMessage(
        handle,
        WM_COPYDATA,
        (WPARAM)(HWND) Handle,
        (LPARAM)(LPVOID) &data);
    if (r == 1)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The call to FindWindow() returns a handle. It must be correct, because if I close the TForm of the dll, then FindWindow() returns nullptr, and if I open it back, it returns a handle again.

The problem occurs with SendMessage(). I can't get the dll TForm message loop responding to the WM_COPYDATA message. I use the following code in the dll form:

```
void __fastcall TCalibrateForm::ApplicationEvents1Message(tagMSG &Msg, bool &Handled)
{
    if (Msg.message == WM_COPYDATA)
        Handled = true;
}
```

And as a second try, in the TCalibrateForm class definition:

```
void __fastcall Prueba(Messages::TMessage&);
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_COPYDATA, Messages::TMessage, Prueba)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(inherited);
```

Neither of the two attempts responds to the message. Any idea what might be happening? Thanks a lot!